# Why do I have to escape double quotes in my string surrounded by single quotes?

Tags: php

I have a variable which I set to an HTML tag (drop down menu):

```
$weapon_secondary = '<select name="weapon" class="dropdown">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
</select>'
```

Running my PHP file gives me

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'weapon' (T_STRING) in C:\web\submit_build.php on line 437

As soon as I escape the double quotes, the parser works just fine. I thought strings in single quotes were taken 'as-is'? This code works just fine:

```
$weapon_secondary = '<select name=\"weapon\" class=\"dropdown\">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
</select>'
```

Why do I have to escape double quotes within single ones?

Comment: You're correct that you shouldn't have to escape double quotes within single ones. There must be something else going on. Is that snippet actually line 437 from your file? What's in the surrounding code? Relevant man page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error must be somewhere else.

see working example : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m6g-25w

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing semicolon `;` at the end of your variable assignment.

It should be:

```
$weapon_secondary = '<select name="weapon" class="dropdown">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
</select>';
```

As an alternative you can use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to declare a variable and avoid this quoting exercise:

```
$weapon_secondary <<< EOF
<select name="weapon" class="dropdown">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
</select>
EOF;
```

Comment: I believe the asker simply omitted it from the posted code, as he mentions that adding the escape backslashes to the string fixes the issue.

Comment: @Crontab: Sorry if I misunderstood the question but otherwise I see nothing wrong in OP's example.

Comment: The error was unrelated to my code that I provided.

I had something along the lines of $x= "...' a few lines up.

Sorry guys!

Answer (score 0):

You *shouldn't*, there must be some misconfiguration going on here. Make sure that [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) are disabled in your [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.php) file.